# Rails: How to start/stop long-running websocket connections to external services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

This is a general/architecture question. I may be misunderstanding some key points here, forgive me if so.

**What a want to achieve**: Monitor an external websocket URL (e.g. Binance websockets) for messages using an existing Ruby on Rails application, deployed on Heroku. Have the ability to start websocket connections, check their status, stop them and restart them.

**Question**: How can I reliably spawn the websocket connections when the application boots? How can I close/restart the connections on-demand, or monitor which websockets I am connected to? How does one ensure connections are kept open, and ideally not duplicated?

The websocket may time-out after 24hours - how would one manage reconnections in a reliable manner?

My websocket connections use the Websocket Simple Client (https://github.com/shokai/websocket-client-simple) and that logic is fine, but not sure on how to start/maintain/restart these listeners in a thread safe and reliable manner.

Example method on a module:

```
module BinanceApi
  require 'uri'
  require "openssl"
  require 'websocket-client-simple'
  include HTTParty

  def self.listen_for_depth(symbol='BTCUSDT')
    path = "/ws/#{symbol.downcase}@depth"
    WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect "#{ENV['BINANCE_WS_URL']}#{path}" do |ws|
      ws.on :open do
        puts "Connected to #{ENV['BINANCE_WS_URL']}#{path}"
      end

      ws.on :message do |msg|
        puts msg.data
      end

      ws.on :close do
        self.listen_for_depth(symbol)
      end      
    end    
  end 
end
```

Comment: How did you end up implementing?